# How to send data through URL via Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to send email addresses from a google sheet to an external web page via Google Scripts, but it doesn't seem to be working.

From reading other similar issues it seems that I need the doPost() function but I'm unsure how I should incorporate it into my script.

Here's my google script

```
function getEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var myUrl = 'https://my.url/';

  if(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if(i !== 0) {
        postToForm(myUrl, data[i][0]); 
      }
    }
    deleteData(sheet, data);
  }
}
function postToForm(url, data) {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + 'user/add/?email=' + data);
}
function deleteData(sheet, data){
  for (var i = data.length; i>1; i--) {
    sheet.deleteRow(i); 
  }
}
```

and here is the receiving script:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
      if (location.search) {
        const urlSearchParams = location.search;

        try {
          await DB.ready();

          const email = getUrlParameter('email', urlSearchParams);

          if (email) {
            emailSignUp(email)
            return;
          }

        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          showSnackBar('Something went wrong', false);
          return;
        }
      }
      showSnackBar('Something went wrong', false);
    });

    function getUrlParameter(key, urlSearchParams) {
      key = key.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
      var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + key + '=([^&#]*)');
      var results = regex.exec(urlSearchParams);
      return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }
</script>
```

Maybe I need to change the postToForm function to doPost and add it that way?

Thanks

Comment: You can use this code generator for making HTTP requests with Google Scripts https://www.labnol.org/apps/urlfetch.html

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

On one hand there is [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app), it is designed to fetch resources and communicate with other hosts over the Internet. On the other hand there is, [doPost](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#dogete_and_doposte) that runs when an `HTTP POST` request is sent to a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). It is developed by the user using Google Apps Script and publishing the script as `web app`.

In your case, as you are calling an external web, you need to use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) in a proper way. In the documentation there are two [examples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) that show how to make the [HTTP request](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html), however your case looks different. Usually, when you make an `HTTP POST` request to send data to a server, you put that data on the message body request but depending on the design of your `API`, you can send data through the query component of the URI.

In your case, the code will look like this:

```
function postToForm(url, data) {
  var uri =  url + 'user/add/?email=' + data
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : ''
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(uri, options);
}
```